# Why will my label not change location when trying to add additional text field?

Tags: swift, uiview, animatewithduration

So I have a button on my storyboard. When that button is pressed, I want to move a certain label down a little bit and also add a new text field to the screen. Here is the simplified code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.addIngredientLabel.center.y += self.addIngredientLabel.bounds.height

            }) { (_) -> Void in

                let newIngredientTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(100, 110, 100, 100))

                newIngredientTextField.center.y -= 50
                newIngredientTextField.placeholder = "place text here"
                newIngredientTextField.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left

                self.view.addSubview(newIngredientTextField)


        }
```

The problem though, is that after the animation is completed, the label jumps back to its original location. It is like the animation is being pre-maturely terminated. The textField gets added and the label moves but it does not stay moved.

I have tried adding the text field at the end of the function instead of in a completion block. No kind of reordering seems to be helping.

I feel like I am not understanding something fundamental to animations. If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For anyone reading this, I thought I'd mention that this problem goes away if you make every UI element part of a scroll view

Comment: do you have constraints on your label?

Comment: Yes, the label is fully positioned in the storyboard with an outlet in the code.

Comment: so your label is constrained by your Autolayout , trying to add an `NSLayoutConstraint` IBOutlet from your storyboard. In the last animation closure, change the `constraint.constant = newValue`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the storyboard, you are most likely also using auto-layout.   The positions of your controls are determined in your visual design (storyboard) and will adjust automatically to orientation changes and adapt to various device screen sizes.   This is good but the flip size is that you cannot directly change the positions of your control using their x,y coordinates.

Instead, you can change values in the constraints you defined in the storyboard.   for example, if you button has a "Top" distancs constraint with a control above it (or the edge of the view), you can change the constraint's "constant" attribute to indirectly change the position of the control.

In order to manipulate the contraints in your code, you can create IBOutlets for them just as you would do with any control.